MongoDB Authentication Fails on Azure Deployment but Works Locally (TLS Error)
I'm deploying a .NET Framework Web API to Azure. It works perfectly on localhost, but when deployed, I get the following error:
EventId: 2
SpanId: ac0bae3952c35f94
TraceId: 8e3f0812c05588cebf217ffcb0a86392
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 40001022-0002-f100-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /api/users/user_2mYgw5xmqerXmATwIDOsbsCAMXR/tokens-balance

Connection ID "17365880172535877665", Request ID "40001022-0002-f100-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Exception: 
System.TimeoutException: A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = ReadPreferenceServerSelector{ ReadPreference = { Mode : Primary } }, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/discuzzdata-shard-00-00.m6szj.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/discuzzdata-shard-00-00.m6szj.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'InternalError'.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.SslStreamFactory.CreateStream(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Open(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.Heartbeat(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2024-09-27T21:28:57.8558628Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2024-09-27T21:28:57.8558629Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/discuzzdata-shard-00-01.m6szj.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/discuzzdata-shard-00-01.m6szj.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'InternalError'.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.SslStreamFactory.CreateStream(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Open(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.Heartbeat(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2024-09-27T21:28:57.8569986Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2024-09-27T21:28:57.8569988Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/discuzzdata-shard-00-02.m6szj.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/discuzzdata-shard-00-02.m6szj.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'InternalError'.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.SslStreamFactory.CreateStream(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Open(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.Heartbeat(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2024-09-27T21:28:57.8558179Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2024-09-27T21:28:57.8558181Z" }] }.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedAsync(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServerAsync(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.IClusterExtensions.SelectServerAndPinIfNeededAsync(ICluster cluster, ICoreSessionHandle session, IServerSelector selector, IReadOnlyCollection`1 deprioritizedServers, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ReadPreferenceBinding.GetReadChannelSourceAsync(IReadOnlyCollection`1 deprioritizedServers, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableReadContext.InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableReadContext.CreateAsync(IReadBinding binding, Boolean retryRequested, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.AggregateOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(IReadBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.CountDocumentsOperation.ExecuteAsync(IReadBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteReadOperationAsync[TResult](IReadBinding binding, IReadOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteReadOperationAsync[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, IReadOperation`1 operation, ReadPreference readPreference, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at DiscuzzServer.Repositories.UserRepository.UserExistsAsync(String userId) in /Users/dennissavchenko/Desktop/DiscuzzServer/DiscuzzServer/Repositories/UserRepository.cs:line 20
   at DiscuzzServer.Services.UserService.GetBalanceAsync(String userId) in /Users/dennissavchenko/Desktop/DiscuzzServer/DiscuzzServer/Services/UserService.cs:line 19
   at DiscuzzServer.Controllers.UsersController.GetBalanceAsync(String userId) in /Users/dennissavchenko/Desktop/DiscuzzServer/DiscuzzServer/Controllers/UsersController.cs:line 17
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()

It seems like there is an issue with the connection to MongoDB Atlas, related to TLS or SSL configuration. I have already tried modifying the connection string based on suggestions from similar problems, but nothing has worked so far. My connection string looks like this:
"mongodb+srv://Stavoker:*******@discuzzdata.m6szj.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=DiscuzzData"

You should add at least tls=true to your connection string. And I assume you also need tlsCAFile=...

I hope, that's not your real password, otherwise you should change it now. Can you connect with other tools, e.g. mongo shell mongosh?

@WernfriedDomscheit I can connect to the database I run my server on localhost or mongosh. The error appears when I tun my server on a cloud (I have tried Azure and Google Cloud).

I was also getting the same error.
[Error] WebApplication4.Controllers.HomeController: 
        MongoDB connection failed: A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = ReadPreferenceServerSelector{ ReadPreference = { Mode : Primary } }, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/mongodbcluter-vivek-shard-00-00.pu5cw.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/mongodbcluter-vivek-shard-00-00.pu5cw.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: 
        An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
    ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'InternalError'.
    ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
        at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.SslStreamFactory.CreateStream(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---



The reason I found for the error was that the current IP address was not added to the network access rules in MongoDB Atlas.

I using a simple connection successful method
My code:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MongoDB.Driver;


namespace WebApplication4.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        // MongoDB connection string
        private readonly string _connectionString = "mongodb+srv://xxxxx:xxxxxx@mongodbcluter-vivek.pu5cw.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=mongodbcluter-vivek";

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        // Home page route
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content("Welcome to the Web API!");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("connect")]
        public IActionResult ConnectToMongoDB()
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new MongoClient(_connectionString);

                return Ok("Connection to MongoDB Atlas is successful!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"MongoDB connection failed: {ex.Message}");
                return StatusCode(500, "Failed to connect to MongoDB Atlas.");
            }
        }
    }
}


OUTPUT:
After Adding the current Ip Address in MongoDB Atlas. It worked for me.


Note : if it still does not work. If possible try using  allow access from anywhere method to check if issue is related to Ip address access issue or TLS issue, in your case.


